# Можно ли обратиться к содержимому комментария, зная адрес ячейки?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

По сути это два смежных вопроса (get и set).

- Можно ли в google sheets подтянуть комментарий или примечание с ячейки, зная её адрес (например, вставить содержимое в другую ячейку)?
- Можно ли в google sheets установить комментарий или примечание на ячейку?

Под "можно" понимается наличие соответствующей формулы и/или скрипта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К примечаниям можно получить доступ скриптами. Используйте метод getNotes() для считывания или setNotes() для установки, применяя к range. Комментарии, насколько я знаю, никак не отслеживаются.